# Akka and cake pattern

Tags: akka, cake-pattern

I'm confused how to ensure that my Actors have the appropriate dependencies using the cake pattern. I'm still getting to grips with this, and I can't find any examples anywhere. I'm basically just looking for a tutorial/resource to follow.

Cheers, Chris.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Actors as dependency:

```
trait DBComponent {
   def db: ActorRef // no compile time guarantees

   type K
   type V

   object DBActor {
      case class Put(key: K, value: V)
      case class Get(key: K)
   }

   class DBActor {
      import DBActor._
      val db = scala.collection.mutable.Map.empty[K, V]
      def receive = {
         case Put(k, v) => db.put(k, v)
         case Get(k) => sender ! db.get(k)
      }
   }
}

trait ServiceComponent {
   this: DBComponent =>

   import DBActor._

   // you could be talking to deadLetters for all you know
   def put(k: K, v: V): Unit = db ! Put(k, v)
   def get(k: K): Option[V] = {
      implicit val timeout = Timeout(5 seconds)
      val future = ask(actor, Get(k)).mapTo[Option[V]]
      Await.result(future, timeout.duration)
   }
}
```

Actors having dependencies (where there is nothing special to it):

```
trait DBComponent {
   def db: DB

   type K
   type V

   trait DB {
      def put(key: K, value: V): Unit
      def get(key: K): Option[V]
   }
}

trait ServiceComponent {
   this: DBComponent =>

   object ServiceActor {
      case class Put(key: K, value: V)
      case class Get(key: K)
   }

   class ServiceActor {
      import ServiceActor._
      def receive = {
         case Put(k, v) => db.put(k, v) // db is in scope
         case Get(k) => sender ! db.get(k)
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: What about the other way around, not things having actors as dependencies, but actors having dependencies, which is what I think the OP was asking about.

Comment: But my issue is that when ServiceActor needs to pass a message to OtherServiceActor then the standard way that I read seems to be using the "context.actorOf[OtherServiceActor]" method to create the required actor. At this point, I get errors if the OtherServiceActor is wrapped in a trait as it unable to instantiate it in that scope.

Comment: Ok, started typing on hell of an edit and realized the answer to my own questions half way through.

Comment: Does the Actor class defined in a trait work? As far as I know Akka actors can't be **non-static inner classes** or it will fail with `akka.actor.ActorInitializationException: exception during creation`

Comment: Ok, just tried it and it does throw that exception if instantiated with `system.actorOf(Props[ServiceActor])` but works with `system.actorOf(Props(new ServiceActor))`

Answer (score 2):

One additional gotcha, as pointed out by Owen, is that creating actors using `actorOf(Props[MyClass])` won't work for inner classes.  Ie: the following will fail:

```
trait MyComponent {
  class MyActor {
    def receive = ...
  }
}

new MyComponent {
  val myActorRef = system.actorOf( Props[MyActor] )
}
```

According to the documentation at http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/actors.html,

> if they are not declared within a top-level object then the enclosing
>   instance’s this reference needs to be passed as the first argument

However, this does not seem to be supported by the scaladoc Props method signatures.  The only way around this I found was to use the Props(actor: Actor) constructor, instantiating the actor mysql and passing it to Props.

```
val myActorRef = system.actorOf( Props( new MyActor(arg1, arg2) ) )
```

Would be interested to know if there's a better way..

Comment: You could use actorOf(Props(classOf[SomeActor], someArgument)).